# Why does this flatMap return a Map instead of a list?

Tags: scala, flatmap

I am trying to convert the below `Map[T,List[T]]` to a `List[T]` using a combination of flatMap and map

```
val numMap = Map(1 -> List(2) , 3 -> List(2,4))
val numPairs = numMap.flatMap{ case (n, nlist) => nlist.map (x => (x,n) ) }
```

The result is a `Map`

```
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 3, 4 -> 3)
```

instead of the expected `List`

```
List((2,1), (2,3), (4,3))
```

Although I could arrive at the intended result with a sequence of `map` operations

```
scala> numMap.map{ case (n, nlist) => nlist.map (x => (x,n) ).toList }.flatten
res20: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (2,3), (4,3))
```

I want to understand why the usage of flatMap failed.

Comment: Because, there are two variations of `flatMap` for a **Map** one will return another **Map** if the return type of the function is another collection of tuples. There are two alternatives, one is to force the other overload through type parameters `numMap.flatMap[(Int, Int)] { ... }`, however this one will return an **Iterable[(Int, Int)]** instead of a **List**. Other alternative is to use an **Iterator**, `numMap.iterator.flatMap { ... }.toList`.

Comment: The `flatMap` operation on a monad should return another monad of the same type,  so the real question is why `Map.flatMap` **doesn't** return another `Map`!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez if this was always the case, why does the  following return a List

```scala> Map(2 -> 3, 4 -> 3).flatMap { case (k,v) => List(k,v) }
res29: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 3)```

Comment: @Benny I am not sure what exactly you are asking, it can not be a **Map** because that is not a **List** of **Tuples**, that is a **List** of **Ints** with two elements. That is why you get back an **Iterable** _(not a **List**)_ of **Ints** - You may say, that you see a **List** there, but that is the _runtime_ `class`. The _static_ `type` of the variable is **Iterable**. For the compiler, only `types` exists, you can no safetly use that as **List**, only as an **Iterable**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks! The accepted answer has clarified the difference between the two variants of Maps. You are right, I was misled by the runtime class `List`, however I didn't know that the runtime class can be different from static type. Where can I find further information about this?

Comment: @Benny it is simple because `List` is a subtype of `Iterable` - Thus, the implementation is free to chose it, without breaking the contract. You can do that in any place, that is the principle of subtyping. Also, you may be interested in [this blog](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html) that explains the differences between _compile time_ **types** and _runtime_ **classes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [scala doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html) there are two versions of `flatMap` function: **One that returns a new iterable collection** while the **other that returns a new map**.
The type of the resulting collection is guided by the static type of iterable collection, which might cause unexpected results sometimes.

In simple words, in case the function that we provided in `flatMap` argument returns a single element, we will be returned iterable collection. On the other hand, if the function in `flatMap` argument returns a collection, we will be returned a new Map.

For e.g. here is your input variable:

```
scala> val numMap = Map(1 -> List(2) , 3 -> List(2,4))
```

If we return only single element from the function argument in `flatMap`, we get `List`

```
scala> numMap.flatMap{case(k,v) => v}
res0: List(2, 2, 4)
```

or (another way to return single element)

```
scala> numMap.flatMap{case(k,v) => v.map(e => e)}
res1: List(2, 2, 4)
```

However, if we return a collection from the function in `flatMap`, we will get `Map`. Here we are returning tuple `(<element of list>, <key>)`

```
scala> numMap.flatMap{case(k,v) => v.map(e => (e,k))}
res2: Map(2 -> 3, 4 -> 3)
```

In case we want return the collection from the `flatMap` function argument, we can use `case class` and get the `List`:

```
scala> case class MyCollection(a: Int, b: Int)
scala> numMap.flatMap{case(k,v) => v.map(e => MyCollection(e,k))}
res4: List(MyCollection(2,1), MyCollection(2,3), MyCollection(4,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

> I could arrive at the intended result with a sequence of map operations
>
> ```
> scala> numMap.map{ case (n, nlist) => nlist.map(x => (x,n)).toList }.flatten
> res20: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (2,3), (4,3))
> ```

Rather than performing additional transformations for the desired result type, consider using [`breakOut`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html):

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

val numPairs: List[(Int, Int)] =
  numMap.flatMap{ case (n, nlist) => nlist.map((_, n)) }(breakOut)
// numPairs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (2,3), (4,3))
```

With the `numPairs: List[(Int, Int)]` type annotation, `breakOut` collects the resulting data into a `List[(Int, Int)]` while bypassing generation of intermediary collections.

Comment: Certainly this seems to be a better way to achieve the results. But sorry that I didn't select this as the correct solution, as the objective of my question was to understand how flatMap ought to behave.